# Resigned before accepting a conditional offer

Tags: references, job-offer

I made a very rash decision now I am regretting it to the bone. I accepted a conditional letter from a company for a full time job while working in a per-week job. I was asked when I would like to resume and I filled in two weeks in order for my Criminal check and Background information to be received.

Then after I gave my notice within the company. I know its a rash thing to do but I told my boss because I knew they will call him up for references. He then countered the offer with something quite close to the offer given to me. I rejected it after taking a week to consider with the hope that my references will have been back due to the living condition of the environment.

Now the other company came back to me after about a week and three days saying they have not even started the background checks yet asking me to shift my resumption by one week to enable them finish the screening. I have resigned already and I have two days to go.

What are my options? Do I even have any left?

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about "options" for temporarily holding off your resignation, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct

Comment: Hate to say it, but the new company not starting the background checks yet is a red flag.  Crap HR or they just don't care about people.

Comment: See http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/947/54 I did something similar. Probably will turn out OK unless you have some reason to expect the background check won't pass. It is better to say something like "I can start X weeks after receiving 'firm' offer (meaning background check complete)". That will then put pressure on the new employer to get it overwith.

Comment: @RichardMorgan - I do not think it is so much a dont care... more likely a money/time to do job issue.  But I agree it is a red flag.  If the company is out of money it makes getting paid hard.  If the company is overburdened with work... well who wants to work 120 hours a week no matter how much you are getting paid.

Comment: @persistence911 so what happened ? did it turn out good?

Comment: thanks all for the contribution. I will keep this in mind next time. Everything went on fine and I secured the job finally.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It sounds like it is already a bit too late.  Take it as a lesson learned that it is harder to build a relationship than to break one.  You said "No" to your current employer *twice*, so staying with them now only damages your credibility in their eyes.

If the offer is solid, just ride the week out as unexpected vacation time.  If you have any doubt that the offer won't materialize then use the time off to redouble your efforts in landing a job.  Realistically, you can't hurry the new employer, and presenting your particular dilemma to them might damage their opinion of your judgement.

Sometimes you can ask to start *contingent* on a successful screening; however, in today's environment that is *very unlikely* to occur.

In the future, let your prospective employer know that they are *absolutely not* permitted to call your current employer for references until *after* a job offer is made.  Make it a point of professionalism, indicating that you would hope nobody would upset their business by performing such a disruptive task.

Comment: +1 for the idea of offering the new employer a *contingent start*. Most companies I've experienced leave recruiting to the last possible moment, so are really happy when people can start earlier than they expected.

Comment: thanks all for the contribution. I will keep this in mind next time. Everything went on fine and I secured the job finally.

Comment: I'm very happy to hear it went well.